# What doesn't html <p> work correctly while returning from JAVA?

Tags: java, html, jax-rs

My environment is Wildfly, using JAX-RS, I am returning a mock response which looks something like this.

```
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
            .entity("<p aat:\"\">sh</p>")
            .type("text/html")
            .encoding("ut-8")
            .build();
```

and looking at the browser, I see what it is converted into if it was text/html

```
< p aat:""="">sh< /p>
```

But, while returning as application/json, it works pretty fine!!!

The response:

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity("<p aat:\"\">sh</p>")
                .type("application/json")
                .encoding("utf-8")
                .build();
```

In browser:

```
< p aat:"">sh< /p>
```

So, the question is how does it get translated, so that it gets converted, which it isn't supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Your html response is not valid html, because the attribute aat may not be followed by a ":" but a "=" character. Try this:

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
        .entity("<p aat=\"\">sh</p>")
        .type("text/html")
        .encoding("ut-8")
        .build();
```

Of course it was not valid json either.